# Mi programa no hace nada al compilar

Tags: c

Mi código no realiza ninguna accion al compilarlo ¿alguien me podría ayudar
debido a que soy principiante en esto y no encuentro el error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf
int j=0,g=0,a,b,c;
int main()
{
 menu();

}
void datos(){
    p("\n ingrese el inicio: ");
    s("%i",&a);
    p("\n ingrese el limite: ");
    s("%i",&b);
    c=a;
    for(j=a;j<b;++j){
        ++c;
        if(c % 5 == 0){
            p("%i\t",c);
        }
    }
}
void datos2(int x, int y){
    c=x;
    for(j=x;j<y;++j){
        ++c;
        if(c % 5 == 0){
            p("%i\t",c);
        }
    }
}
int datos3(){
     p("\n ingrese el inicio: ");
    s("%i",&a);
    p("\n ingrese el limite: ");
    s("%i",&b);
    return (a,b);
}
int datos4(int i){
    p("\n la secuencia inicia en: %i",i);
     p("\n ingrese un numero: ");
    s("%i",&b);
    return (b);
}
void menu(){
    int q=0;
    do{
    p("\n seleccione el tipo de funcion que desea:\n1.-bacia \n2.-con parametro \n3.-con retorno \n4.-con parametro y retorno \n5.-cuadrado magico \n6.-salir: ");
    s("%i",&q);
    switch (q){
case 1:
    datos();
    break;
case 2:
    p("\n ingrese el inicio: ");
    s("%i",&a);
    p("\n ingrese el limite: ");
    s("%i",&b);
    datos2(a,b);
    break;
case 3:
    datos3();
    c=a;
    for(j=a;j<b;++j){
        ++c;
        if(c % 5 == 0){
            p("%i\t",c);
        }
    }
    break;
case 4:
     p("\n ingrese un numero: ");
    s("%i",&a);
    p("\n el limite es: %i \n ",datos4(a));
     c=a;
    for(j=a;j<b;++j){
        ++c;
        if(c % 5 == 0){
            p("%i\t",c);
        }
    }
    break;
case 5:
    magico();
    break;
    }
    }while(q!=6);
}
void magico(){
    int matriz[3][3],m[4]={0,0,0,0},n[4];
for(j=0;j<3;++j){
    for(g=0;g<3;++g){
        p("\n ingresa el valor de la posicion[%i][%i]: ",j,g);
        s("%i",&matriz[j][g]);
    }
}
    for(j=0;j<3;++j){
    for(g=0;g<3;++g){
    m[j]=m[j]+matriz[j][g];
    }
    p("\n %i",m[j]);
    }
    if(m[0]==m[1] && m[1]==m[2]){
        n[0]=1;
    }
    for(j=0;j<3;++j){
        m[j]=0;
    }
     for(j=0;j<3;++j){
    for(g=0;g<3;++g){
        m[g]=m[g]+matriz[g][j];
    }
    p("\n %i",m[g]);
  }
  if(m[0]==m[1] && m[1]==m[2]){
        n[1]=1;
    }
    for(j=0;j<3;++j){
        m[j]=0;
    }
   for(j=0;j<3;++j){
   m[j]=m[j]+matriz[j][j];
   }p("\n %i",m[j]);
   if(m[0]==m[1] && m[1]==m[2]){
        n[2]=1;
    }
    for(j=0;j<3;++j){
        m[j]=0;
    }
   for(j=2;j>=0;--j){
   m[j]=m[j]+matriz[j][j];
   }p("\n %i",m[j]);
   if(m[0]==m[1] && m[1]==m[2]){
        n[3]=1;
    }
    if(n[0]==n[1] && n[1]==n[2] && n[2]==n[3]){
        p("\n es un cuadro magico");
    }
    else{
        p("\n no es un cuadro magico");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa que no realiza ninguna acción al compilar?

Comment: Salvo por una llave que falta al final, el programa compila sin errores (aunque tiene warnings porque las funciones que implementas no fueron declaradas al inicio). Una vez compilado, si se ejecuta sale un menú, pregunta cosas.. no sé qué se supone que debe hacer por lo que no sé si funciona correctamente, pero al menos funciona.

Comment: Puedes indicar cómo lo estás compilando para que sea más fácil identificar el error

Comment: Prueba definir la funcion main de la siguiente manera: int main(int ac, char** av) en vez de int main()